# R install `KFKSDS` on mac

Tags: r, macos

I am trying to install tsoutliers library in R where only the source is available and it doesn't has a CRAN package available. Also, KFKSDS in one of the dependencies that have to be installed, again, it is source code version available only.

I used `brew` to have `gsl` installed but when I tried to install `KFKSDS`, it still errorred out. On the other side, I installed `gsl`, `gsl-devel`, `KFKSDS` and `tsoutliers` easily on the redhat server. Can anyone show me how can I installed it successfully on my Mac. I am using R 3.1.1 which is not cutting edge but should be good enough, I guess.

```
> install.packages("KFKSDS", type="source")
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/KFKSDS_1.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 30272 bytes (29 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 29 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘KFKSDS’ ...
** package ‘KFKSDS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c KF-deriv.cpp -o KF-deriv.o
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.h:1539,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/basic_ios.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:50,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iterator:70,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/numeric:67,
                 from KFKSDS.h:12,
                 from KF-deriv.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/codecvt.h:219:45: error: macro "length" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 1
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/locale_facets.h:1539,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/basic_ios.h:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:50,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:45,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iterator:70,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/numeric:67,
                 from KFKSDS.h:12,
                 from KF-deriv.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/codecvt.h:218: error: expected ‘;’ before ���const’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/codecvt.h:222: error: expected `;' before ‘int’
make: *** [KF-deriv.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘KFKSDS’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/KFKSDS’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘KFKSDS’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
  ‘/private/var/folders/d2/ffftfj193ng339zrc3jbdv75m9ssv9/T/RtmpgJshhe/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: The CRAN Checks log say that there is a problem with linking to some 'gsl' header and  I get a lot of errors relating to missing gsl headers when I try to install from source.

Comment: @BondedDust I did `brew install gsl`, and I got it installed on my mac. Some of my colleagues have it installed however, I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: i had the same issue installing tsoutliers in R on linux mint, i had to install gsl via apt-get